# How do I get machine name off of the SPContext

Tags: spcontext

Simple question... how do I get the machine name off of the SPContext object.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe [SPServer.Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460171.aspx) is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would use SPContext for that - perhaps you are looking for this instead: [Environment.MachineName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try *HttpContext.Current.Server.MachineName*

Answer (score 0):

POSH Scripts to get you server info

(Get-SPServer has other params - check for unique server)

$myserver = Get-SPServer
$myserver | select-object *

Comment: there should be line after Get-SPServer (this editor didn't pick it up)